# How do I detect an audio file starting to play from a webView url

Tags: ios, audio, web

I have a simple IOS app that uses a webView to load various infomraiton 
Most information is HTML, but the URL passed to the webView may be an audio file. When this happens IOS launches a mediaplayer which is fine.
I've got a timer that is started in the webViewDidStartLoad method and invalidated in the webViewDidFinishLoad method. This timer causes clicking sounds to be played. It seems that when an audio file is launched, the webViewDidFinishLoad method isn't triggered until you close the mediaplayer.
How can I stop the timer before the mediaplayer starts so the user doesn't hear the progress clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the webview is launching MPMoviePlayerController instance when the audio url is encountered.

If it is, then you can register to MPMoviePlayerController notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

The selector will be called when the audio data is loaded.